# Fixing title page aligning

Tags: titles

I need to achieve what's on this screenshot 1:

> screenshot 1
>   [image]

I cannot make the title look the same in terms of aligning in mine (screenshot 2). Both **T**s start at the same place in the first shot, while in mine, it does not.

[LOGO SOURCE](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/Logo-fcenuba.png)

> screenshot 2
>   [image: Screenshot2]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\usepackage{lmodern} 

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{titlepage}
    \newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} 

\begin{center}
    \vfill\vfill
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{Logo-fcenuba.png}\\[1cm] % Include a department/university logo - this will require the graphicx package



    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Headings
    %------------------------------------------------

    \textbf{\LARGE Universidad de Buenos Aires}\\[1.5cm] 

    \Large Facultad de Ciencias Exactas y Naturales Departamento de Fısica\\[0.5cm]
%   \textsc{\large Minor Heading}\\[0.5cm] 

    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Title
    %------------------------------------------------



    {\huge\bfseries Transporte cuantico dependiente del tiempo en sistemas mesoscopicos}\\[0.4cm] 

    \large Tesis presentada para optar al tıtulo de Doctor de la Universidad de Buenos Aires area ciencias fısicas


    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Author(s)
    %------------------------------------------------


    % If you don't want a supervisor, uncomment the two lines below and comment the code above
    {\Large\textbf{John Wick Thompson}}\\
    %John \textsc{Smith} 

    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Date
    %------------------------------------------------

    \vfill\vfill\vfill 

%   {\large\today} 


    \vfill % Push the date up 1/4 of the remaining page
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem with the `adjustwidth` environment (from `changepage`) to enlarge the text area  on the right side (only for this page). I also shortened the vertical spacing between the logo and the university name.

```
 \documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters

\usepackage{lmodern} % Palatino font
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{titlepage} % Suppresses displaying the page number on the title page and the subsequent page counts as page 1
    \newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % Defines a new command for horizontal lines, change thickness here
\begin{adjustwidth}{-2em}{-5em}
\begin{center}
    \vfill\vfill
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{Logo-fcenuba.png}\\ [1.5ex] % Include a department/university logo - this will require the graphicx package
    %------------------------------------------------
    % Headings
    %------------------------------------------------
    \textbf{\LARGE Universidad de Buenos Aires}\\[2.5ex] % Main heading such as the name of your university/college

    \Large Facultad de Ciencias Exactas y Naturales\\ Departamento de Fısica\\[7ex] % Major heading such as course name

% \textsc{\large Minor Heading}\\[0.5cm] % Minor heading such as course title

    %------------------------------------------------
    % Title
    %------------------------------------------------



    {\huge\bfseries Transporte cuantico dependiente del tiempo en sistemas mesoscopicos}\\[0.4cm] % Title of your document

    \large Tesis presentada para optar al tıtulo de Doctor de la Universidad de Buenos Aires\\ area ciencias fısicas\medskip


    %------------------------------------------------
    % Author(s)
    %------------------------------------------------


    % If you don't want a supervisor, uncomment the two lines below and comment the code above
    {\Large\textbf{John Wick Thompson}}\\
    %John \textsc{Smith} % Your name

    %------------------------------------------------
    % Date
    %------------------------------------------------

    \vfill\vfill\vfill % Position the date 3/4 down the remaining page

% {\large\today} % Date, change the \today to a set date if you want to be precise

    %------------------------------------------------
    % Logo
    %------------------------------------------------


    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \vfill % Push the date up 1/4 of the remaining page
\end{center}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{titlepage}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Bernard, but you did all the modifications to my example instead to the one needed. I want mine to look like the first screenshot. There you can see both words "Transporte" and "Tesis" start at the same place.

Comment: I've modified the code. Is it more like you want?

Comment: Yes!!! That's exactly what I wanted! I was guessing the whole thing. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: You're welcome! Just a suggestion: I would split the sentence starting with `Tesis presentada` in three lines, so that it be no wider than the thesis title above (for instance `para optar al  titulo de \\  Doctor ... Buenos Aires \\ area ciencias fisicas`

Comment: I just noticed a new one, this is a beauty! The format I am using is `a4paper` and everything we've done so far is in `letterpaper`. Could you keep the same harmony in terms of spaces but using `a4paper`?

Comment: All what  should be done, I think, would be to adjust (by trial and error) the values of the parameters of the `adjustwidth` environment. Also, note that if you already load `geometry`, all this could  as well be done  with the `\newgeometry`  command.